# Find out if my cell is part of a group of merged cells and the size of this group

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an excel document and I would like, for a cell, to find out if it is part of a merged region, and, if so find out the coordinate of this merged region.

I found some methods like  CellRangeAddress getMergedRegion(int index)
But the CellRangeAddress class don't a method of any use in my case.

(I don't know the format of the excel document in advance)

Does anyone have a solution ?

Edit: Nevermind, CellRangeAddress inherit getFirstColumn, getFirstRow, getLastColumn and getLastRow methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, CellRangeAddress inherit getFirstColumn, getFirstRow, getLastColumn and getLastRow methods.